# How to track my local branches flow with Git?

Tags: git

In the picture below i see my branches as tree from the master. How can i get the same graph with my local folder before pushing every thing to Github? I want to see that if my current branch come from the master?

Sorry if the name is not telling my issue very clear but just because i don't know what is that called and how to do it. BTW any modification by your side i will be so appreciated.

[image: Github Network]

Comment: Do you mean something like `git log --graph --oneline --all`?

Comment: Wow that's magic haha. Work like a charm. Please add your answer to make it the best answer.

Comment: @MikeTung How to track the local ones?

Comment: done, glad I could help

Comment: I added two flags to help you get only Local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git log --graph --oneline --all --not --remotes=*
```

was what OP wanted

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want BUT can i make the same graph with my local folder ? for the moment it is every thing about the Github and nothing from my local folder.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, if your local folder is initialized with git then you should be able to. But again hard to say

Answer (score -2):

You can install a programme for that like [**Sourcetree**](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

Comment: Well after Mike Ting answer i found also another simple way to see your local tree by writing this code on your repository gitk --all